How to disable annoying popups when using Winforms Designer?
Lately I'm getting a lot of messagebox popups when I'm trying to open a Form or UserControl in Designer mode. It's like any debug log message had it's output set as a messagebox, and I cannot find how to disable it. But it's worse because it's like it's executing the form and even accessing code that is marked to be skipped if it's in design mode.

Anybody can help me how to disable this "feature"?

Which .Net version are you using? .Net Framework (4.8) or .Net (Core)?

I'm using .Net 6

Check the Trace.Listeners collection and see whether one of these has AssertUiEnabled = true (well, it should be the default) and see whether switching it off helps (maybe that's a Serilog injected TraceListener?)

But it's the Designer window. Where is the Trace.Listeners collection for Windows Form Designer?

I have the same issue. In my case, the message boxes came from a Debug.Print instruction which are located in custom form class.
As a matter of fact, in Google search, "Windows Forms Trace Listener" search leads to this topic only.

Same issue here. Very annoying popup message on each debug run. VS 2022 17.11.2, dotnet 8.0.400
